# Why does gcc compile f(1199) and f(1200) differently?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, micro-optimization

What causes GCC 7.2.1 on ARM to use a load from memory (`lr`) for certain constants, and an immediate (`mov`) in some other cases?  Concretely, I'm seeing the following:

GCC 7.2.1 for ARM compiles this:

```
extern void abc(int);
int test() { abc(1199); return 0; }
```

…into that:

```
test():
  push {r4, lr}
  ldr r0, .L4  // ??!
  bl abc(int)
  mov r0, #0
  pop {r4, lr}
  bx lr
.L4:
  .word 1199
```

and this:

```
extern void abc(int);
int test() { abc(1200); return 0; }
```

…into that:

```
test():
  push {r4, lr}
  mov r0, #1200  // OK
  bl abc(int)
  mov r0, #0
  pop {r4, lr}
  bx lr
```

At first I expected 1200 to be some sort of unique cutoff, but there are other cut-offs like this at 1024 (1024 yields a `mov r0, #1024`, whereas 1025 uses `ldr`) and at other values.

Why would GCC use a load from memory to fetch a constant, rather than using an immediate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has to do with the way that constant operands are encoded in the ARM instruction set.  They are encoded as an (unsigned) 8-bit constant combined with a 4 bit rotate field -- the 8 bit value will be rotated by 2 times the value in that 4 bit field.  So any value that fits in that form can be used as a constant argument.

The constant `1200` is 10010110000 in binary, so it can be encoded as the 8-bit constant 01001011 combined with a rotate of 4.

The constant `1199` is 10010101111 in binary, so there's no way to fit it in an ARM constant operand.